# Knockout foreach binding creating extra columns

Tags: html, knockout.js

can someone tell me why there's extra td columns in the following foreach binding?

```
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 5px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>rid</th>
        <th>ciname</th>
        <th>dId</th>
        <th>ReqName</th>
        <th>ReqType</th>
        <th>bus</th>
        <th>Req test</th>
        <th>no trace</th>
        <th>p r</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqid' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: ciname' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: did' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqname' /><td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqtype' /><td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: bus' /><td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqtest' /><td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: notrace' /><td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: pr' /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

jsfiddle link here:
http://jsfiddle.net/g3j94273/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td` not closed properly

```
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 5px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>rid</th>
        <th>ciname</th>
        <th>dId</th>
        <th>ReqName</th>
        <th>ReqType</th>
        <th>bus</th>
        <th>Req test</th>
        <th>no trace</th>
        <th>p r</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqid' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: ciname' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: did' /></td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqname' /><td>
                                              ^^
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqtype' /><td>
                                              ^^
        <td><span data-bind='text: bus' /><td>
                                           ^^
        <td><span data-bind='text: reqtest' /><td>
                                              ^^
        <td><span data-bind='text: notrace' /><td>
                                              ^^
        <td><span data-bind='text: pr' /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Use

http://jsfiddle.net/g3j94273/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your  tags are not properly closed, you need to convert some of the `<td>` to `</td>`

```
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 5px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>rid</th>
            <th>ciname</th>
            <th>dId</th>
            <th>ReqName</th>
            <th>ReqType</th>
            <th>bus</th>
            <th>Req test</th>
            <th>no trace</th>
            <th>p r</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind='text: reqid' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: ciname' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: did' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: reqname' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: reqtype' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: bus' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: reqtest' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: notrace' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text: pr' /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, its probably fair to accept Tamil's answer as he was a few secs earlier